# How to Auto select a selectbox using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

can anyone help me how to autoselect a selectbox if there is a value on it.

I want to do is my selectbox will automatically select `admin aid VI` but my script wont work can anyone help me with this.

html code:

```
<select id="position">
<option></option>
<option>admin aid VI</option>
</select>
```

script code:

```
<script>
$("#position").val(1).trigger('selected',true);
</script>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

try this

```
$("#position option").eq(1).attr("selected",true);
```

or

```
$("#position option:contains(admin aid VI)").attr("selected",true);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are setting with value in script and you don't have value in options
Change the Options like this:

```
<option value=1>admin aid VI</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   //loop all options
    $('#position option').each(function(){

      //$(this).val() is the value of the option
      if ( $(this).val() != "" )
      {
          $(this).attr('selected',true);
      }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#position").val("admin aid VI");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Eb7NZ/